# Submitting to MySQL, but if statement causing issues

Tags: php, mysql, forms

The form is submitting, but the $id variable is behaving strangely, while the $part variable is behaving as expected.

The first if statement works perfectly, but all of the rest will submit the $part variable, while setting the $id variable to "0". Any clue what could be happening?

```
 <?php    
    $part = $_POST['participating'];
    $form = $_POST['forms'];
    $meth = $_POST['method'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if ($meth == "Forms - Foo") {
        $sql="INSERT INTO form_foo (id, participants, forms)
              VALUES ('$id', '$part', '$form')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    } else if ($meth=="Forms - Other") {
        $sql="INSERT INTO form_other (id, participants)
              VALUES ('$id', '$part')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    } else if ($meth=="Online - Foo") {
        $sql="INSERT INTO online_foo (id, participants)
              VALUES ('$id', '$part')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    } else {
        $sql="INSERT INTO online_other (id, participants)
              VALUES ('$id', '$part')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: -1 for using `mysql_query` in 2014.  For the love of all that is good, read up about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Particularly pay attention to the stuff about prepared statements.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's coming across the wire? You're simply assuming your client-side form is set up correctly. Since you only assign `$id` in ONE spot in your code, there's no way it could work in one way and not the other. It's not conditional code. That means something upstream is screwing up, which means it's probably your form.

Comment: And to continue what @cHao set, -infinite for being vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and -double_infinity for having absolutely no error handling in your code. assuming a query always succeed borders on the criminal.

Comment: @cHao He can use mysqli instead of PDO and prepared statements for it

Comment: I disagree with OP getting a -1 for using `mysql_` functions and think it's uncalled for. We don't know if that is all OP can use or is restricted to using it. We can only instruct OP to use the latest in APIs. Downvoting just because, isn't a valid reason.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I code in a legacy universe I will be using mysql_* until i die

Comment: But Dagon, at least you use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function to mitigate SQL Injection vulnerabilities ala "Little Bobby Tables" [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @BDillan: That'd work too (though i seem to remember mysqli being a bit more complicated to set up parameters).  But meh.  I've said my piece about ext/mysql in my profile, which hasn't changed in probably a year or two.

Comment: You'll need to post your form including examples on how you're using it. There is no way for anyone here who will be able to give you a definite answer. You have 3 different tables, one of which has 3 columns and 3 values, while the other two tables have two.

Comment: This is a perfect candidate for a `switch` statement.

Comment: Is your $id autoincrementing in the DB? If it is, then you don't need to provide an ID inside insert mysql statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Any clue what could be happening?**

**A:** One way to get a clue about what's happening would be to output the contents of `$sql` before the call to `mysql_query`.

A simple echo, vardump, printf would be one way to get the actual SQL that's being submitted to the database. From there, that will help you determine whether the problem is upstream, in getting the SQL statement built, or downstream, in executing the statement in the database.

Also, it's a good idea to check the return from `mysql_query`. The return will be FALSE if there's a MySQL error. And there's a `mysql_error` function that can return the text of the last MySQL error.

---

Just guessing here, but the most likely explanation for the behavior you are observing, the contents of `$id` variable starts with something other than digit characters. MySQL tries to get a number out of the leading portion of a string literal. And an empty string will evaluate to zero in a numeric context, consider:

```
SELECT '2b3c' + 0    => 2
SELECT 'a1b2' + 0    => 0
SELECT ''     + 0    => 0
```

It's very unlikely that the `if` statement is causing an issue; we don't see any assignment being done, apart from assigning a value to `$sql` variable. The `if` block you posted has only a conditional test.

If the SQL text being submitted looks reasonable, e.g. `... VALUES ('456','foo')`, then we'd need to take a closer look at the database. (Like, did someone create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger containing `SET NEW.id = 0;`? Is the column `id` declare to be `INT`, and you are expecting it to be `VARCHAR`. We're just guessing.

---

Also, you may want to consider SQL Injection vulnerabilities, when "unsafe" values are included in SQL text. The `mysql` interface, provides a `mysql_real_escape_string` function that does a good job of making "unsafe" values "safe" for inclusion in a SQL statement.

Comment: While I do appreciate the feedback, even a downvote, if this answer can be improved, or this answer doesn't address the question that was asked, or if there's some problem with this answer, then please feel free to leave a comment. Thanks!